# How can I speed up SFTP?

Tags: sftp

I'm on a setup that requires me to use SFTP to send files to my server. It takes a 2-4 seconds for the SFTP server to connect, and every time I change folders, it's another 1-2 seconds for the file list to update. This gets old fast ;-) Is there any way to speed up SFTP?

I have full control over the server that I'm uploading to, so I can use a different type of protocol/server if that's the answer.

Comment: For faster file transfers, try FTP.

Comment: Because of encryption, SFTP is inherently slower than FTP. In a similar situation, I found upgrading to higher-spec SFTP servers helped greatly. More RAM, faster CPU.

Comment: Related: [Why is FileZilla SFTP file transfer max capped at 1.3MiB/sec instead of saturating available bandwidth?](https://serverfault.com/q/694062/168875) – It's not the same question. But what is important that you first need to find out if the problem is bandwidth, latency or CPU. Without that we cannot advice you how to solve your problem.

Comment: This depends hugely on your bandwidth and the size of files you are uploading. I don't think we can answer this.